# FullCalendar does not display past events. How to store lastCreatedEvent date?

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar

Whenever i insert an event and that day passes it just disappears from my calendar. I have a different page where i load all the events and they're still there so they are not being removed from the database.

There must be a check somewhere in the FullCalendar code which makes it that it doesn't display dates < $today. I have no clue on where to start looking, is there anyone who had the same problem as me? How did you manage to fix it? Thank you for reading my question.

Also, how would i go about storing the last created event day? For example, i want to create a function which brings the users to my event created in August instead of today's date.

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar( 'gotoDate', LASTCREATEDDATE );
```

I need it to update whenever somebody creates a new event.

I looked for different functions on how to achieve this but i'm not quite sure how to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that you are not getting the right events to be showed.

As you can read [here](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/event_data/events_json_feed/) FullCalendar is going to send the following URL to the server:

/myfeed.php?start=2013-12-01&end=2014-01-12&_=1386054751381

So you have to select from your database the events which EventStartDate <= end && EventEndDate >= start

About your second question you should use something like [SignalR](http://www.asp.net/signalr) or [WebSockets](http://dev.w3.org/html5/websockets/)  if you want the calendar of your users to be updated as soon you create a new event.

Comment: As much as i appreciate your answer, isn't there an easier way to store the last created even date?  And i've read the Json feed piece but i can't seem to understand it :/

Comment: Well, you will have to connect to the database at least when a user first connect to your calendar right? You could take the last inserted id on your events table and take the date from it. I don;t thinks there is another way basically. You need the database and take or the last date or the last id before retrieving your events.

Comment: hmm yeah, that does make sense. Also, when i use

viewRender: function(view, element) {
 
  $('#rst-calendar').fullCalendar( 'gotoDate', 2014, 2, 24 );
 
 },

it's stuck on that month. I can't press next/prev/today. Is that because it loads a certain view or something?

Comment: First Problem solved! Thank you for that answer :) It works lovely now. All that's left is that piece of code ^^ It's just stuck there.

Comment: I pretty much created a whole new view just for that gotoDate. That's why it was stuck. I just put that single Goto line in the main view and now it's working properly :)